# I want to write SOQL query listing all FieldPermissions but without formula/calculated fields

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, soql

I need to write a SOQL query listing all FieldPermissions without the formula/calculated fields

The query I wrote is:

```
SELECT Id, Field, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit 
FROM FieldPermissions 
WHERE parentId IN ( SELECT id 
                    FROM permissionset 
                    WHERE PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator')  AND SObjectType='Simploud__Controlled_Document__c' AND (PermissionsRead=false OR PermissionsEdit=false)
```

The query run successfully but grabs also calculated/formula fields. How can I modify it to return only rows with non-formula/calculated fields?

I am asking because then I want enter the result into list, and then run apex code to iterate the list and change all the  PermissionsRead and PermissionsEdit to true.

I tried writing this apex code in 'Developer Console' - 'Open execute anoymous window' :

```
public List<FieldPermissions> exampleTwo = new List<FieldPermissions>([SELECT Id, Field, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit 
FROM FieldPermissions 
WHERE parentId IN ( SELECT id 
                    FROM permissionset 
                    WHERE PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator')  AND SObjectType='Simploud__Controlled_Document__c' AND (PermissionsRead=false OR PermissionsEdit=false)]);

for(FieldPermissions t : exampleTwo){
    t.PermissionsRead=true;
    update t;
}
```

The code runs sucessfully but nothing was changed in fact.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to write a SOQL query listing all FieldPermissions without the formula/calculated fields

This can be achieved by preparing a list of non-calculated fields on the target object and using that list to fetch field permissions for only non-calculated fields and other filters you have applied. A Sample Code is attached below for your reference :-

```
List<FieldDefinition> nonCalculatedFieldsDefinitions = [Select QualifiedApiName,EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName from FieldDefinition where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'Simploud__Controlled_Document__c' and IsCalculated = false];
List<String> nonCalculatedFieldsNames = new List<String>();
for(FieldDefinition nonCalculatedFieldsDefinition : nonCalculatedFieldsDefinitions){
    nonCalculatedFieldsNames.add(nonCalculatedFieldsDefinition.EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName+'.'+nonCalculatedFieldsDefinition.QualifiedApiName);
}
List<FieldPermissions> exampleTwo = new List<FieldPermissions>([SELECT Id, Field, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit 
FROM FieldPermissions 
WHERE parentId IN ( SELECT id 
                    FROM permissionset 
                    WHERE PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator')  AND SObjectType='Simploud__Controlled_Document__c' AND (PermissionsRead=false OR PermissionsEdit=false) AND Field IN :nonCalculatedFieldsNames]);

for(FieldPermissions t : exampleTwo){
    /*Proccessing*/
}
```

(Here we used FieldDefinition object which stores all information about a field in Salesforce to find out whether a field is a calculated one or not. And prepared a list of fieldnames first in required format as stored in 'Field' column of FieldPermissions object.)

> The code runs sucessfully but nothing was changed in fact.

Regarding this, I also tried update on field permissions and it works. I think the problem in your case might be that you are performing DML inside loop which is not suggested so try following :-

```
List<FieldPermissions> fieldPermissionsToBeUpdated = new List<FieldPermissions>();
for(FieldPermissions t : exampleTwo){
    t.PermissionsRead=true;
    fieldPermissionsToBeUpdated.add(t);
}
update fieldPermissionsToBeUpdated;
```